# Adding index to vuejs class

Tags: vuejs2

I spend a few hours on this and got somewhat further than I expected. But this seem to be a roadblock.

This is for an inventory form. So far everything seem to work correctly. In simple a new field will be added for each item in stock. The user can now pick the color, add a quantity and a comment.

The problems is that I can not figure out how to add the index value to the class. I can get the index value at the bottom but now when I add it to a class.

My other inputs look like this one.

```
<input type="text" name="option[1][option_name]" class="form-control" id="example" value="blue">
```

However when I generate these they come up like this i cant figure out how to add the index number to the name.
Any help is appreciated it.

```
<input type="text" name="option[{{ index }}][quantity]">
```

https://codepen.io/virgiltu/pen/gqBwwj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply bind the attribute (with `v-bind:name` or `:name`) and use template literals:

```vue
<input type="text" :name="`option[${index}][${option_name}]`" class="form-control" id="example" value="blue">
```

Comment: Awesome I know I was using something wrong. I guess there is a difference between '' and `` in vue. Thank you so much.